# UIImagePickerController on iPhone 4 device

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, screenshot

This is no typical programming question.
I am currently developing an app using the latest SDK. This app will use the UIImagePickerController for taking pictures with the built-in camera.
I know the new iPhone 4 has 2 cameras built in. But the simulator doesn't support the camera in any way, so there's is now way to test the camera controller on a new iPhone. I do have a iPhone 3G to test my app with.

But what I want to know now, if someone can provide me a screenshot of the UIImagePickerController in camera mode running on his iPhone 4? But I really need an image from the UIImagePickerController not from the common camera application on the iPhone, because those two image pickers aren't the same! I can see this on my iPhone 3G: the built-in camera application and the UIImagePickerController are having a totally different UI.

Why I am asking for that? Because I want to know if there is a built-in switch in UIImagePickerController to switch between the front and rear camera. I know there is such a switch if you want to take a picture using the common iPhone 4 camera application, but I don't know if this switch also exists in UIImagePickerController from the SDK.

Thanks for your help!

C YA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I managed to catch it with the zoom control and focus square.
[image]

Comment: Wow! Great thanks! So it seems the UIImagePicker on an iPhone 4 automatically shows the switch to change between front and rear camera. Great! You helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time ;).

C YA